# Transfer variables from Python to C#

Tags: python, c#, text-files, opencv

I'm making a project with OpenCV-Python and GUI C#(Winform). I want to save a variable "data" in python and write it to txt file. Then transfer it to GUI C# by run python script from c# and read the value of "data" from txt file.
But I got the problem: When I change the value of "data" and press the button 1,  it didn't display the value of "data" right away. It just showed the previous value of "data" and I had to press 2 more times. Then it can display correctly.
Please tell me what should I do.
My Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

file = open("D:\\Data\\VisualStudio2019\\python-cs\\pytocs.txt","w")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    data = "123"
    file.write(data + "\n")
    

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        file.close()
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My C# code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RunPython();
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
static void RunPython()
        {

            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = @"C:\Users\tramn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe";

            var script = @"D:\Data\VisualStudio2019\python-cs\PythonApplication1\pythontotext.py";
            psi.Arguments = $"\"{script}\"";

            // Process configuration
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

            //Execute process and get output
            Process.Start(psi);
            
        }

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Data\VisualStudio2019\python-cs\pytocs.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
            {

                string data = reader.ReadLine();
                textBox1.Text = data;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your python process and timer almost start at the same time, so it was possible the FileStream start before the python write line to your file.

And sense you are trying to keep reading the file, check out this [Timer.AutoReset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.autoreset?view=net-5.0) to make your timer not only run once.